# How do I get nice tick labels for an irregularly sampled time series?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a Pandas Series sampled at irregular times (roughly 5 s, but always a couple of ms off due to latency).

Can I plot this data to have **nice x-axis tick labels**? So far I am getting only this:

```
>>> print(bare_data.index)
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-11-08 12:00:05.130309, ..., 2012-11-09 11:38:18.997584]
Length: 16332, Freq: None, Timezone: None
>>> bare_data.plot()
```

[image]

After consulting the Pandas documentation I found that this can be made prettier by resampling and interpolating the data:

```
>>> bare_data.resample('5s').interpolate().plot()
```

[image: resampled data]

But this introduces potential errors, though, depending on my original sample times, so I am wondering if there is a loseless way to get pretty tick labels, given that the *index is consisting of Timestamps even in the first scenario*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regular frequencies pandas converts the underlying index into a PeriodIndex before plotting and uses a different set of tick formatters and locators for PeriodIndex.

As a workaround for now, you can use `rot` to rotate the ticks so they don't overlap. It won't be as pretty as the second plot but it'll at least be readable.

I made an issue here on github (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2235).

Comment: I see. Thanks for opening the issue. Could you please clarify on how to use `rot`? I tried doing something like `bare_data.plot(rot=60)`, but it doesn't change anything. The [only docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) I found on the parameter don't say much.

Comment: OK, the `rot` option started working now. I think it was due to me using an old 0.9 development version that came with the SciPySuperpack bundle. The tick are readable when I do `bare_data.plot(rot=60)` or `bare_data.plot(rot=90)`. Thanks!